# Error in ROS MoveIt! while loading an URDF

Tags: urdf, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Everyone,

I am new to the world of ROS and MoveIt!

I was following a Tutorial for MoveIt! from Youtube but unfortunately I seem to have hit a dead end !

The link to the video is : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l4dtSRvlAjg&t=211s \

The files can be found here : https://github.com/andrewneill/abb_irb1600id_support

I was wondering if anyone has seen errors similar to what I am getting in my system.  I have attached a log of the Errors and Warning which I am getting.

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/4d8f49c1054b1c319811f7dd509b609e

I would be very grateful if someone can try to import the URDF and suggest ways to eliminate the issues I am facing.

Btw, I am using Ubuntu 14.4 and ROS Indigo.

Any leads would be deeply appreciated.

Kind Regards,
Sagnik Basu Choudhuri

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260902/error-in-ros-moveit!-while-loading-an-urdf/) by [Jalashwa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29518/jalashwa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-05-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
[ERROR] [1493769151.230318708]: Error retrieving file [package://abb_irb1600id_support/meshes/irb1600id/visual/link_6.stl]: Package [abb_irb1600id_support] does not exist
```

I actually feel like this is one of the few times where the error message is quite clear: it basically tell you that the package `abb_irb1600id_support` cannot be found anywhere.

Do you actually have that package in your workspace?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jalashwa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29518/jalashwa/) on 2017-05-03**:
Hey there,

Thanks for getting back to me.

I did realize that and did move the package to my Workspace. I did that once again later in the day and it worked like a charm.

Thanks a lot fot your help, I am sure I made some mistake the first time round.

**Comment by [Jalashwa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29518/jalashwa/) on 2017-05-03**:
Could you please help me with this error as well as in where do I need to look :

[ERROR] [1493846706.675530121]: Error retrieving file [package:///robot_simulation/meshes/End_link_R01.stl]: Package [] does not exist
[rospack] Error: no package given
[librospack]: error while executing command

Ty

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-04**:
I'm not sure I understand you: have you placed the `abb_irb1600id_support` package in your workspace, built your workspace, `source`d the `setup.bash` and then retried? That should be enough to at least avoid the errors you've copy-pasted.